# pxe boot pass variable to submenu

Tags: grub2, pxe, netboot

I'm using RHEL 8 and I currently have the ability to install a single image the LAN. I'm trying to expand our options such that we can select from several images. I'd like to have a top level menu where I can select image A,B,C. Then it would call a submenu and pass in the selected imaged. The menus and submenus work but I cannot figure out how to pass a variable from the top level menu to the lower menu. For example if I want to pass image A into the submenu this is what I've tried..

```
BUILD="A"
append pxelinux.cfg/Config BUILD="$BUILD"
```

Then in the submenu

```
menu being
menu title BUILD="$BUILD"
```

When I boot the system it does not show the variable it just prints

```
BUILD="$BUILD"
```

So my question is am I passing in the variable correctly? How do I display the variable in the menu?

Comment: Just a shot, without the double quotes?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I tried removing the quote on the submenu and it did not work. `menu title BUILD=$BUILD` Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Well, a failed shot.

Comment: Mmh, [this is related I think, and may answer your question](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=SYSLINUX#Is_There_A_Way_To_Define_Constants_Or_Variables.3F).